# Read all data during single recv() method from a socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to continuously read the data using socket programming. I use recv() which receives data on a socket. I store it in a buffer. recv() returns the number of bytes read. Following is the snippet:

```
while (true) {
        try {
            char buff[2048];
            int bytes = recv(sockfd, buff, 2048, 0);
            buff[bytes] = '\0';
            cout << strlen(buff) << endl;
            cout << bytes << endl;
            cout << "-------" << endl;
        } catch (const char *e) {
        }
    }
```

Following is the output of the code:

```
1
1204
-------
1
1390
-------
1
25
-------
1
1204
-------
```

The number of bytes received are correct through recv() method but I am not able to read the exact number of data. How can I read all the data captured during single recv() method?

Comment: C or C++, which is your programming language? Remove the tag that doesn't fit.

Comment: If your question why don't you get 2048 bytes in a single `recv` call? `recv` just returns whatever bytes are available at the time, it doesn't wait for all the bytes to be available

Comment: Also note that `buff[bytes]` is *incredibly* dangerous. An error condition will result in `recv` returning a `-1`, and your program is destined for the abyss of undefined behavior thereafter with `buff[bytes] = '\0';`

Comment: Which sockets API does your question refer to? Does your question refer to [POSIX sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) or [Windows Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock) or some other sockets API?

Comment: Or is your problem with the `strlen` result? That is telling you that there is one non-zero byte inside buffer followed by one zero byte. Your data could look like that for all we know. What did you expect to get instead?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel POSIX sockets.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'll apply the condition. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Depending on the type of data, the data that you received may contain bytes with the value `0`. In that case, calling `strlen` on this data will not return the length of the received data. It will contain the index of the first byte with the value `0`.

Comment: I think you should specify what type of socket you have, what data you send/want to receive (example data when you think the code above doesn't work).

Comment: So, I am trying to convert a python code to C++ code. You can view the source code of the both files and can suggest me the changes. `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16Or2Tx6Dj1P4lk9LKpn66kCkGJLbPnmt?usp=sharing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `strlen` will treat the contents of `buff` as a null-terminated string and return the length of that string.

In the line

```
buff[bytes] = '\0';
```

you wrote a null terminating character at the end of the data. That way, you have ensured that the data is null-terminated.

However, it is possible that the bytes that were read by `recv` contain a byte with the value `0`. The function `strlen` will be unable to distinguish between such a byte and the actual terminating null character. It will simply return the index of the position of the first byte with the value `0`.

That is why the expression `strlen(buff)` does not correspond to the actual length of the data.

For this reason, you should not be using the function `strlen` on binary data. That function is only intended for text data, which cannot contain a character with the value `0`, except to mark the end of the string.

Instead of using `strlen` to determine the length of the data, you should only be using the value returned by `recv` (which you have stored in the variable `bytes`). As long as you remember this value, you will always know the length, so there is no need to mark the end of the data with a terminating null character.

Provided that `recv` returned a positive value (negative would indicate failure), you will find all of the data in the array `buff`, and the return value of `recv` will specify the length of the data. If you want to, for example, print all of the data that you have received in your function call to `recv`, you could write the following immediately after the `recv` function call:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < bytes; i++ )
    cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill( '0' ) << static_cast<int>(buff[i]) << ' ';
```

Note that you must add `#include <iomanip>` at the start of your program for this line to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass proper flag to recv as in documentation. Basing on: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html
there is flag MSG_WAITALL (since Linux 2.2) that do what you want.

The call would look like:

```
int bytes = recv(sockfd, buff, 2048, MSG_WAITALL);
```

---

And checking length of received bytes by strlen is bad unless you are sure you receive only text.

Comment: I get the flag part but MSG_WAITALL does not return all the data.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal: I find that hard to believe. What makes you think that it did not return all the data? Did you look at the return value of `recv`? Or did you look at the return value of `strlen`?

Comment: I am comparing both of them. When I set flag as 0, I get the return value of `recv` correctly but it does not match with `strlen`. When I use `MSG_WAITALL`, the return value of `recv` is always 2048 which is not correct.

Comment: Well... so your question is incorrect. You receive proper number of bytes but you check it by strlen. I guess you don't receive ASCII raw string but some other data. WAITALL waits for data until buffer is filled or disconnect (or any other error) occurs

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal If the buffer size is 2048, `MSG_WAITALL` will still receive at most 2048 bytes. If the data you're receiving contains any zeros, `strlen` will not be the same as the received amount.

Comment: @KarolT. I said that the number of bytes received are correct through recv() method but I am not able to read the exact number of data. How can I read all the data captured during single recv() method?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I i apologize for my poor english. What I wanted to say is that Value returned by `recv` indicates that it has read correct number of bytes. But then, I try to read char[] buff variable and the length of the buff variable is less than value returned by `recv`. I just want a way so that I can just read all the bytes indicated by `recv` method in buff variable

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal Please use debugger to see what is exactly stored in buff and you should see why there is difference between recv and strlen

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal: You will find all the data that was read by `recv` in the array `buff`. If `recv` returns `2048`, then you can use `buff[0]` to `buff[2047]` to read the individual bytes/characters. If `recv` returns `100`, then you can use `buff[0]` to `buff[99]`. There is no point in calling `strlen`.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal: If you want to see the values of the individual bytes that you received in hexadecimal representation, then you can insert the following line of code immediately after the function call to `recv`: `for ( int i = 0; i < bytes; i++ ) cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill( '0' ) << static_cast<int>(buff[i]) << ' ';` Note that you must add `#include <iomanip>` at the start of your program for this line to work.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you can post it as answer so that I can accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `std::string_view` pointing at the data read.

```
while (true) {
    char buff[2048];
    int bytes = recv(sockfd, buff, 2048, 0);
    if (bytes >= 0) {
        std::string_view read { buff, bytes };
        std::cout << read << std::endl;
        std::cout << "-------" << std::endl;
    } // else?
}
```